# How do I change the email address that Amazon SES feedback reports go to?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

**Background:** I was handed the reins for our company's AWS account to implement a process to make sure our SES delivery report notifications can get acted on instead of just being filed away or deleted.

That said, the first hurdle is that the email address associated with our company's helpdesk keeps receiving all Amazon SES notifications for bounces, complaints and delivery failures. This creates a mess for our support staff in having to wade through these emails individually, and our ticketing system doesn't have the capability of auto-forwarding emails even though I can categorize them based on rules when they arrive.

I have read through all the knowledge base articles for SES notifications as well as ~380 forum topics relating to email notifications, but I didn't see an answer posted this question even though it had been asked a handful of times.

**What we've done**:

- Set up a dedicated email inbox for these requests so we can then process them correctly (that we want to divert these messages to).
- Created an SNS topic with the new email address as its endpoint and applied it to all categories, but the emails still kept going to support, so that clearly wasn't the solution.
- Removed all hard-coded references to these emails from our software code, but we still get individual Amazon SES notifications to the helpdesk (~30 a day).

Simple idea, but AWS is pretty intimidating especially for our small company where no one has taken the time to learn through the ins and outs after first setting it up (fire and forget).

**Edit** for clarity, the emails I'm trying to redirect are "Delivery Status Notification (Failure/Delay)" and "Undeliverable:..."

Comment: Did you check all your company wise SNS notifications?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but under the SNS Dashboard, the only items present are three topics- one for bounces, one for complaints, and the custom topic I made for the new email to receive notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how i got this to work:

Under "AWS SNS"

1. Create an SNS Topic
2. Create a subscription to the topic that sends an email to your desired "catch address"
3. Confirm this subscription by clicking the link sent by AWS to this address

Under "SES Management - Identity Mangement"

1. Verify a domain or email address
2. At the domain/email address go to Notification and DISABLE Email Feedback Forwarding
3. Same place select your SNS topic for Bounces and Complaints

Under "SES Managment - Email Receiving"

1. Create a Rule set and then create a rule with the domain or email address above
2. Make the action the SNS rule above

When sending mail be sure that the From address is using the domain/email address above. All bounces and complaints should now end up in the catch address inbox. ALL OF THIS must be setup in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

These notifications are configured either at a verified Domain level or at a verified email address level.  This [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console) has info on it.  At the bottom, it talks about how you can confirgue to have messages sent to email or a SNS topic. You probably have a notification setup on your domain or the specific email address you are using.

You'll find all this in the SES section of the AWS Console under the Identity Management section. Make sure you check both the Domains area and the Email Addresses area.

Answer (score 0):

You make the feedback address differ from the sender by setting the `Return-Path` header in your message (subject to a few other rules):

From the [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity-using-notifications-email.html#monitor-sending-activity-using-notifications-email-destination):

> If you used the SMTP interface to send the message, then notifications go to the address specified in the MAIL FROM command.
>
> If you used the SendEmail API operation to send the message, then the notifications are delivered according to the following rules:
>
> - If you specified the optional ReturnPath parameter in your call to the SendEmail API, then notifications go to that address.
> - Otherwise, notifications go to the address specified in the required Source parameter of SendEmail.
>
> If you used the SendRawEmail API operation to send the message, then the notifications are delivered according to the following rules:
>
> - If you specified a Source parameter in your call to the SendRawEmail API, then notifications go to that address. This is true even if you specified a Return-Path header in the body of the email.
> - Otherwise, if you specified a Return-Path header in the raw message, then notifications go to that address.
> - Otherwise, notifications go to the address in the From header of the raw message.